# JSON.parse array from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

Hi I have an associative array in my php file which I pass to my js file as a JSON object. I want to loop through the array and find the item in the array with the matching key. This is what I have so far:

php:

```
<?php
$countries = array(
"United Kingdom"=>"pounds", 
"United States"=>"dollars", 
"France"=>"euros",
"Germany"=>"euros",
);
echo json_encode($countries);
?>
```

js:

```
var location = "United States";
$.get("location.php", function(data){
var locationArray = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

I want to go through the array and find the item that matches with the location variable ("United States"). This should return `"dollars"`.

Comment: Okay, it works. So what's the problem?

Comment: @PraveenKumar How would I loop through the array in JS?

Comment: You don't need to loop it, you can do this `locationArray["United States"]`

Comment: Or reformat the array to have a better structure: `array(array('country'=>'US','currency'=>'dolars'),array('country'=>'Germany','currency'=>'euros'));` Then you can iterate in js and find by country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here You can get your `unites states` data

```
$.get("location.php", function(data){
    var locationArray = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(locationArray['United States']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
var return_value = '';
var location_name = "United States";

for(var key in locationArray)
{
    if(key == location_name)
    {
        return_value = key;
    }
}
// You can use return_value from here in your code further....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it also using this code:

```
for (var key in locationArray) {
    if (key == 'United States') {
        var currency = locationArray[key];
    }
}
```